SIGHUP error handling, exception throws in Scanner class how can I fix this problem?
import java.util.*;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String name=sc.next();
        System.out.println("No more input to read");
    
        
    }
}

This was my code in java for print statement on an online IDE.
it throws me this error

Hangup (SIGHUP)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at GFG.main(GFG.java:9)

I've tried to fix the problem in the syntax, but I want to resolve this expression without using any try catch method like how we use in our common IDE .

I have the solution for the issue,
I think you are trying to run the program in Geeks's Online Compiler.
I case of the Online Compilers the Company serves using a Virtual Machine which restricts the runtime input when comes to run Online.
So they give you a input tab for entering user input before run and the enumerate it when runtime.
The Java Online Compiler also have it
Click To See the User Input place in GFG - Java Online Compiler
use that textarea to give user input each line.
and I don't have access to embed pictures so click the above image link to view.
Thank You.
